# Como remover R$ do NumberFormatter?

Tags: php

Galera estou com o seguinte problema.

Segue meu código:

```
$valores = '530222077.99';
$moeda = new NumberFormatter('pt_BR', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$valores = $moeda->formatCurrency($valores, 'BRL');
echo $valores;
```

O seguinte código me retorna: `R$530.222.077,99`. Porem, eu preciso que me retorne `530.222.077,99`, ou seja sem o `R$`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quando você usa `NumberFormatter::CURRENCY`, está pedindo o "pacote completo", que inclui a moeda e os separadores de milhar e decimal.

Uma opção para a parte numérica é usar `NumberFormatter::DECIMAL`

```
$valores = '530222077.99';
$moeda = new NumberFormatter('pt_BR', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$valores = $moeda->formatCurrency($valores, 'BRL');
echo $valores;
```

Mais detalhes podem ser vistos na **[documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.numberformatter.php#intl.numberformatter-constants)** da classe, em especial a parte das "constantes pré-definidas".

Note que você pode criar seus próprios formatos e máscaras se quiser, com o método **[`NumberFormatter::create`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/numberformatter.create.php)**.

Comment: estou tendo outro problema. se eu colocar um valor 2500 ele me retorna 2.500 ao indez de 2.500,00. Sabe como resolver isso?

Comment: Teste `$moeda->setAttribute( NumberFormatter::MIN_FRACTION_DIGITS, 2 );`

Comment: perfeito funcionou 100%

Comment: poderia me dar mais uma ajuda? estou usando a forma CURRENCY para exibir totais em relatório, pois ela ja vem com o R$. O problema e que quando formata um numero negativo ele fica assim: (R$4.444,44) Sendo que preciso que ele fique assim: R$-4.444,44 Você sabe como resolver isso?

Comment: R$ -4.444,44 não existe :) O que você pode fazer, é usar um IF e colocar, por exemplo, parênteses em volta (ou um sinal de menos antes do R$). Conforme eu comentei em outra ocasião, se quiser realmente customizar muito a saída, é melhor uma função própria de formatação.

Comment: No caso como eu faço para ficar assim -R$4.444,44? Pois tem que ter uma forma de eu representar valor negativo correto?

Answer (score 2):

Bom seguindo o manual do php:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/numberformatter.formatcurrency.php

Cheguei a solução. Que na minha opinião e muito melhor usar o NumberFormatter pois e uma biblioteca nativa do php.

Segue a solução para conversão.

```
$valores = '-99999999.99';

$moeda2 = new NumberFormatter('pt_BR', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$moeda2->setTextAttribute(NumberFormatter::NEGATIVE_PREFIX, "-R$");
$moeda2->setTextAttribute(NumberFormatter::NEGATIVE_SUFFIX, "");

$valores = $moeda2->formatCurrency($valores, 'BRL');
```

Retorna  -R$99.999.999,99

Solução para  reversão

```
$moeda2 = new NumberFormatter('pt_BR', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$valor_puro = $moeda1->parseCurrency($valores, $moeda_bd);
```

Retorna 99999999.99